# Recursive Karatsuba multiplication not working?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to implement [Karatsuba multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) through recursive calls. The code below should work, but I keep getting the wrong answer. Any thoughts?

```
    public static long karatsuba(long x, long y){
        //base case:
        if (x < 10 || y < 10) return x * y;

        //length of digits:
        int xSize = String.valueOf(x).length();
        int ySize = String.valueOf(y).length();
        int N     = Math.max(xSize, ySize);

        //split each number in half (by length of digits):
        long numX_hi = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(x).substring(0, N/2)));
        long numX_lo = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(x).substring(N/2, xSize)));
        long numY_hi = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(y).substring(0, N/2)));
        long numY_lo = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(y).substring(N/2, ySize)));

        //solve multiplications recursively:
        long z0 = karatsuba(numX_lo,numY_lo);
        long z1 = karatsuba((numX_hi+numX_lo),(numY_hi+numY_lo));
        long z2 = karatsuba(numX_hi,numY_hi);

        //answer:
        return  (long)(z2 * Math.pow(10,N))  +  (long)((z1-z2-z0) * Math.pow(10,(N/2)))  +  (z0);
    }
```

Here are a few test cases:

1) karatsuba(1234,5678)  >>>  *6952652*

*should be  *7006652*

2) karatsuba(4589, 7831)  >>>  *34649459*

*should be  *35936459*

3) karatsuba(911, 482)  >>>  *44722*

*should be  *472842*

Comment: Which substrings get selected if `N` is odd, and is `Math.pow(10,(N/2))` the correct scale for this?

Comment: Your program throws exception for: `karatsuba(20,1000)`

Comment: It's probably too late now but I would do it in binary, it's much easier to read and understand. (Not to mention faster.)

Comment: @rtruszk That's probably because there's no check before the `substring()` calls, so if one number is twice as long as the other, `substring()` will fail.

Comment: @greybeard It splits to smaller string, bigger string. E.g. for x = 12345, it splits to `numX_hi = "12"` and `numX_lo = "345"`. Regardless, I get the wrong answer for even digit numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two distinct problems with your method.

Firstly, you should split starting from the last (least significant) digit, not the first. So if you've got these two numbers:

```
1234
567890
```

You currently split them like this:

```
123   4 (123*1000+4)
567 890 (567*1000+890)
```

This gets you the wrong result because `1234 != 123*1000+4`

You should instead split them like this:

```
  1 234  (1*1000+234)
567 890  (567*1000+890)
```

---

The second error I discovered happens when you add things back together.

```
return  (long)(z2 * Math.pow(10,N))  +  (long)((z1-z2-z0) * Math.pow(10,(N/2)))  +  (z0);
```

Will return an incorrect result for odd `N`s, as `N/2` will be rounded <s>up</s> down and therefore `N != ((N/2)*2)`

I've combined the two fixes and now I get the correct results:

```
public static long karatsuba(long x, long y){
    //base case:
    if (x < 10 || y < 10) return x * y;

    //length of digits:
    int xSize = String.valueOf(x).length();
    int ySize = String.valueOf(y).length();
    int halfN     = Math.max(xSize, ySize) / 2; // store N/2 instead of N
    int splitX = xSize - halfN;  // count the split point from xSize down
    int splitY = ySize - halfN;  // count the split point from ySize down

    //split each number in half (by length of digits):
    long numX_hi = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(x).substring(0, splitX)));
    long numX_lo = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(x).substring(splitX)));
    long numY_hi = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(y).substring(0, splitY)));
    long numY_lo = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(y).substring(splitY)));

    //solve multiplications recursively:
    long z0 = karatsuba(numX_lo,numY_lo);
    long z1 = karatsuba((numX_hi+numX_lo),(numY_hi+numY_lo));
    long z2 = karatsuba(numX_hi,numY_hi);

    //answer:
    return  (long)(z2 * Math.pow(10,halfN*2))  +  (long)((z1-z2-z0) * Math.pow(10,halfN))  +  (z0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think you meant `N/2` will be rounded _down_ [due to integer division]. I'll look into creating a binary version, as you suggested -- but not right now; a binary solution might take a while to conceptualize.

Comment: Yes, of course it's rounded down, not up, but the rest of it is still valid. For the binary solution I'd approach it in two steps: in the first step keep the base 10 calculation but try to eliminate all string operations from your method. In the second step rewrite it in base 2, exploiting the fact that dividing by 2<sup>n</sup> can be written as bitwise shifting to the right, and multiplying as bitwise shift to the left.

Comment: As an example you are using 1234 and 567890 but isn't Karatsuba about multiplying 2 numbers with equal amount of digits?

Comment: @Alan That is absolutely true, however you can always pad out the shorter number with leading zeroes (1234 -> 001234 in this case). This is actually what the first error I describe is about.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution gives a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException if the length of one number string is more than twice the other, because the splitX or splitY would be negative.
[image]
To prevent this problem, one must catch this exception and then set halfN to be Math.min(xSize, ySize)/2 . Here is the corrected code:

```
public static long karatsuba(long x, long y){
    //base case:
    if (x < 10 || y < 10) return x * y;

    //length of digits:
    int xSize = String.valueOf(x).length();
    int ySize = String.valueOf(y).length();

    int halfN = Math.max(xSize, ySize) / 2; // store N/2 instead of N
    if (halfN >= xSize || halfN >= ySize){
        halfN = Math.min(xSize, ySize) / 2; // prevents string index error
    }
    int splitX = xSize - halfN;  // count the split point from xSize down
    int splitY = ySize - halfN;  // count the split point from ySize down

    //split each number in half (by length of digits):
    long numX_hi = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(x).substring(0, splitX)));
    long numX_lo = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(x).substring(splitX)));
    long numY_hi = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(y).substring(0, splitY)));
    long numY_lo = Long.valueOf((String.valueOf(y).substring(splitY)));

    //solve multiplications recursively:
    long z0 = karatsuba(numX_lo,numY_lo);
    long z1 = karatsuba((numX_hi+numX_lo),(numY_hi+numY_lo));
    long z2 = karatsuba(numX_hi,numY_hi);

    //answer:
    return  (long)(z2 * Math.pow(10,halfN*2))  +  (long)((z1-z2-z0) * Math.pow(10,halfN))  +  (z0);
}
```

Comment: `one must catch this exception and then ` I'm half relieved to see it coded in a saner way. (In picking a "Karatsuba base/scale", I never quite understood the enthusiasm for splitting the longer factor evenly. While consistent with *left padding the shorter factor with zeroes*, it takes longer to reduce to a base case (without complicating it even more special casing *more significant part of one factor is zero*) than just [using the shorter factor like en.wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Pseudocode) does.)